# Політкоректність особових займенників

Tags: вибір-слова, займенники, фемінітиви

Наскільки правильним/прийнятним буде вживання займенника `вони` для позначення особи, стать якої ми не хочемо акцентувати, як це часом роблять в англійській? Чи маємо в таких випадках вживати займенник тільки відповідно до граматичного роду іменника?

> Якщо подзвонить якийсь кандидат, перекажіть їм (йому? йому/їй? йому або їй? їй або йому?), що вакансію вже закрито.

Comment: А якщо подзвонить кандидатка, тоді що?

Comment: @Follower https://english.stackexchange.com/q/6854/220344

Comment: Тоді краще щось в дусі: _Якщо поздвонить хтось з кандидатів, перекажіть, що вакансію вже закрито._

Comment: Створив теґ [tag:gender-neutrality], потім придумаємо більш вдалу назву

Answer (score 2):

По-перше, треба розуміти, що такі речі у нас на рівні правопису поки що не вреґульовані. Толерантність дуже повільно заходить у профільні комітети.

Поки що жодного разу не чув і не бачив використання займенника "вони" в однині.

У даному конкретному випадку можна замінити *кандидата* на *кандидатів*:

*Всім кандидатам, що дзвонитимуть найближчим часом, перекажіть, що вакансію вже закрито.*

Отже, займенників взагалі можна уникнути, бо у нас є 7 відмінків і множина.

Якщо треба написати щось ще про цих кандидатів - відпадає потреба використовувати *вони* в однині. Кандидати - вони.

Якщо ви не можете змінити речення у такий спосіб, щоби там не потрібні були займенники, то йому/їй, або їй/йому - прийнятні варіанти.

[Ґуґл пошук для йому/їй](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%2F%D1%97%D0%B9%22&oq=%22%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%2F%D1%97%D0%B9%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i30k1l2.1575.3044.0.3321.2.2.0.0.0.0.109.211.0j2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.109....0.kkLzCJHDqkw)